# TFS 2017 - Build and Release

Tags: build, msbuild, release, agent

I am very new in TFS, need to implement CICD using TFS 2017 and its build and release feature, 
when I tried to run build after creating build definition, I got error like no agent found, I googled and found how to configure agent, but I have logical confusion in my mind as below:

1. How Agent works with TFS 2017?
2. Where process of CI will be run on Agent or on TFS server?
3. Where I need to have msbuild ? where my built code will be placed?
4. What other dependencies would be there on Agent machine?

all question might be silly but as I have worked with Jenkins and Git, i dont have knowledge of Microsoft technologies, and I can't find well documents for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How Agent works with TFS 2017?

In short to build with TFS, you need to [Deploy an agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows), in the agent machine you need to install the proper build components/SDKs accordingly based on your project.

[Create a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#create-a-build-definition). Once a build is triggered , the sources will be downloaded from the TFS repository to the agent machine and then build in the agent machine.

Related documents : [Agent pools and queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/pools-queues); [Build and Release Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents); [Build definition options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options)

> 2. Where process of CI will be run on Agent or on TFS server?

You can eanble the CI (turn on the **Continuous integration** trigger) in build definition. See [Configure continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing#configure-continuous-integration) for details. Thus the build will automatically be triggered once changes are checked in.

Related documents: [A quick introduction to CI/CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#a-quick-introduction-to-cicd) ; [Build and release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/)

> 3. Where I need to have msbuild ? where my built code will be placed?

For vNext build, it's task based build system. You can define your build definition based on the tasks. See [Build and release tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/index) .

e.g.: You can use [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/msbuild) or [Visual Studio Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build) task, you can specify the `MSBuild Arguments` as needed.

You can use the utility task: [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) to specify where the built code will be placed. (Artifact Type : Server/File share path)

> 4. What other dependencies would be there on Agent machine?

Refer to the answer for the first question.

Comment: Hey Andy, about question no- 3, I mean , where published code(built code) will be take place- on agent machine or on TFS server machine? about physical location

Comment: @HeenaPatel By default (Artifact Type : `Server`) ,it's in TFS server machine. However you can change the type to  `File share path`, then you can publish the build to any shared location. (with UNC path specified, e.g. `\\sharefolder`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)